# Is there another name for rollercoaster restraints?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there another name for rollercoaster restraints? I tried to look for a synonym, but I couldn't find anything, so I was wondering if there was no other word or phrase to refer to these things.

Comment: "Restraints" works well for me

Comment: If you called them 'safety bars' or 'safety harness' people would know what you mean.

Comment: Is there a reason you need a word other than *restraints*?  [That's what Coasterpedia calls them](https://coasterpedia.net/wiki/Restraints), and that's the most common term.  They do have specific terms for different kinds of restraints, though.

Comment: safety harness sounds better to me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *harness*, as in Coasterpedia's [Over-the-shoulder harness](https://coasterpedia.net/wiki/Over-the-shoulder_harness) page.

See also other [specific terms for restraints](https://coasterforce.com/trains/).